# How to deserialize array of unknown dimension with Gson?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, gson

I tried to use

```
.fromJson(mystring, Object.class);
```

but got nested ArrayList-s.

I want to get nested `double[][]...[]`

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I wrote the following custom adapter

```
public class DoubleArrayAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Object> {


   @Override
   public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {

      if( value.getClass().isArray() ) {
         out.beginArray();
         int length = Array.getLength(value);
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
            Object arrayElement = Array.get(value, i);
            write(out, arrayElement);
         }
         out.endArray();
      }
      else {
         out.value((double) value);
      }

   }

   @Override
   public Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if( in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY ) {
         ArrayList<Object> elements = new ArrayList<>();
         in.beginArray();
         do {
            elements.add(read(in));
         } while( in.peek() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY );
         in.endArray();

         if( elements.size() == 0 ) {
            return new double[0];
         }
         else {
            Class cls = elements.get(0).getClass();
            if( cls.isArray() ) {
               Object ans = Array.newInstance(cls, elements.size());
               for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); ++i) {
                  Array.set(ans, i, elements.get(i));
               }
               return ans;
            }
            else {
               double[] ans = new double[elements.size()];
               for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); ++i) {
                  ans[i] = (double) elements.get(i);
               }
               return ans;
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         return in.nextDouble();
      }
   }
}
```

and prepare Gson object with the following code

```
public static Gson getGsonWithDoubleArrayAdapter() {
      if( gson == null ) {
         gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .serializeNulls()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new DoubleArrayAdapter())
            .create();
      }
      return gson;
   }
```

But looks like it doesn't activate nevertheless (still generates ArrayList-s).

Comment: what is the type of ur current ArrayList?

Comment: @Salman just `ArrayList`. I see it at runtime only.

Comment: You cannot override `java.lang.Object` deserialization in Gson, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Lists instead, since they don't have a set length:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ClassName download = gson.fromJson(input, ClassName.class); // creates POJO from input, into a ClassName object
```

---

In such a way that `ClassName` resembles:

```
public class ClassName {  
    String name;    

    List<ObjInList> list;
}    

public class ObjInList {  
    String description;
    float price;
}
```

I also recommend [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website for this process (no affiliation)

Comment: *I would use Lists instead, since they don't have a set length*. You're completely ignoring the question. Clearly OP has lists already, but wants arrays. And why would you assume variable length is a requirement anyway?

Answer (score 0):

First I found a bug in my adapter, it should be

```
if( in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY ) {
         ArrayList<Object> elements = new ArrayList<>();
         in.beginArray();
         do {
            elements.add(read(in));
         } while( in.peek() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY );
         in.endArray();
```

ans also later

```
 if( cls.isArray() ) {
           Object ans = Array.newInstance(cls, elements.size());
           for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); ++i) {
              Array.set(ans, i, elements.get(i));
           }
           return ans;
        }
```

and so on.

And then I parsed string with this adapter directly, whith the code

```
new DoubleArrayAdapter().fromJson(new StringReader(mystring));
```